# Duda para crear tabla mysql con valores mensuales y trimestrales

Tags: mysql

necesito crear una tabla llamada "evaluacion" en la que una vez al mes de deben ingresar unos valores de una simple formula a/b, es decir un campo para a, otro para b y un tercero para el resultado.
A primeras la tabla quedaria asi: `idEvaluacion,idProducto,fecha,denominador(a),numerador(b),resultado`.

El problema es que no se si esta estructura sirva, porque ademas debo almacenar(o calcular dinamicamente, he alli mi duda)los totales trimestralmente a lo largo del año.
Pensaba  hacer una tabla grande con un campo para cada mes y entre medio otro campo para cada trimestre.

Tengo solo dos tablas para esto:

```
productos
------------
idProducto int,
nombre varchar

evaluacion
-----------------
idEvaluacion int ai,
fk_idProducto int,
fecha datetime,
denominador int,
numerador int,
resultado int
```

Algun consejo?

Comment: Te aconsejo que lo calcules de manera dinamica para no llenarte de datos que no seran necesarios si se pueden calcular cada vez que los usen, no estoy seguro de que tu tabla pueda ser util, al crear una tabla tienes que ver si realmente es necesaria o si puedes generar los informes a partir de las tablas ya existenes.

Comment: no entiendo cual es el problema que ves al calcular totales sobre la tabla. salvo que tengas algun problema con los tiempos, un simple query lo resuelve.

Comment: Como ha dicho @M.Gress **Guarda en tu tabla solamente los datos que sean inmutables**, es decir, los datos que no cambian, los que usarás para hacer tus cálculos. Todo lo demás hazlo de forma dinámica, MySQL tiene infinidad de funciones de cálculo por lo que no tendrás ningún problema.

Comment: ok, entonces como se puede hacer una query para que al ver los datos de un año completo pueda ver los datos de cada mes, y ademas cada tres columnas(de meses) incluir un campo dinamico con los resultados trimestrales? y mostrar todo en una sola fila por año

Comment: Podrias agregar tus tablas que tienes ahorita con los nombres de los campos que tienes para poderte apoyar mejor.

Comment: Mira este ejemplo: http://rextester.com/GQGFV76570 , creo que se aproxima a lo que quieres hacer. Si no, a partir de ahí cualquier modificación es posible.

Comment: gracias es muy parecido a lo que busco, me sirvio mucho

Answer (score 2):

Tu estructura encaja perfectamente para lo que queres hacer.

El otro problema que mencionas, sobre como mostrar los resultados es un problema de la vista y no de la base de datos.

Tus datos se pueden resolver trimestralmente con un query que agrupe por trimestres (podrias tener una columna año-trimestre o calcularla en la misma query) y desde alli en tu vista ir mezclando los datos.

Comment: _Tu estructura encaja perfectamente para lo que queres hacer._ **No del todo.** Yo no pondría jamás un campo calculado en una tabla: `resultado int`, es un error grave.

Comment: @A.Cedano porque no?? si es un datawarehouse, es perfectamente valido y recomendable. por lo que dice el usuario, la estructura es para despues poder mostrar datos, no para hacer ABM sobre ellos, con lo cual esta correcto

Comment: _debo almacenar (o calcular dinamicamente, he alli mi duda)_ El OP tiene dudas al respecto. Si mañana el jefe le pide que quiere, **además** de la división entre A y B,**la suma entre A y B**, y si es antojadizo **y quiere también el 10% del valor de A-B** o que quiere un **informe semestral** y otro trimestral **y además un reporte anual**... pues ya me dirás de que habrá servido introducir campos calculados en el diseño de la tabla. Aparte de que **hay que introducirlos** y para ello habrá que implementar una función de cálculo.

Comment: @A.Cedano OP no especifico el uso de la tabla. Si mañana piden eso la tabla se cambia y se recalcula. Todo depende del uso que se le de a la tabla. los informes mensuales bimestrales o por el tiempo que quieras se calculan con un group by. sigo sin entender el problema. Es mas barato el query a la hora de mostrar que es lo que OP resalto.

Comment: Un diseño de BD en el que cada vez que te piden algo tengas que modificar la tabla es **un mal diseño**, parece que ignoras el precio que eso puede tener en una BD en producción, o en una BD indexada. **¿Y qué tal si el jefe pide un informe por horas, o por minutos**? ¿Hasta cuantas filas y columnas podrían llegar tus tablas? O sea, cada vez que al jefe se le antoje algo ahí te veré modificando tablas y creando código para calcular introducir lo calculado en la tabla... y no te digo nada si te equivocas el algún código que calcule e introduzca datos en al BD. Uffff

Comment: @A.Cedano si queres lo seguimos en el chat... pero todo depende para que se use.. OP no especifico nada al respecto...